# How to do a calculated field in tableau where respondents can select multiple race?

Tags: tableau-api

I have this problem. I was able to do a calculated field for every race group there is. What I am struggling with is the last racial group which is multiple race group/non Hispanic indicated by the Last Elseif statement. Basically respondents who have selected multiple race categories. For example respondents who have selected both white and Asian would be counted as multiple race. Here is my code

```
If [Race White Code]=50 AND [Ethnicity Not Hispanic Code]=20 then 'White Non-Hispanic'
ELSEIf [Race Black Or Af Am Code]=30 AND [Ethnicity Not Hispanic Code]= 20  then 'Black/African American Non-Hispanic'
ELSEIF  [Ethnicity Cuban Code]= 13 OR [Ethnicity Hispanic Non Specific Code]=10 OR [Ethnicity Mexican Code]=11 OR
[Ethnicity Other Hispanic Code]=14 OR [Ethnicity Puerto Rican Code]=12 then 'Hispanic/Latino'
ELSEIF [Race AIAN Code]=10 AND [Ethnicity Not Hispanic Code]= 20 then 'American Indian/Alaska Native Non-Hispanic'
ELSEIF [Race Other Code]=60 AND [Ethnicity Not Hispanic Code]= 20 then 'Other Non-Hispanic'
ELSEIF  [Race Asian Code]=20 OR [Race Asian Indian Code]=21 OR [Race Chinese Code]=22 OR [Race Filipino Code]=23 OR
[Race Japanese Code]=24 OR [Race Korean Code]=25 OR [Race Vietnamese Code]=26 OR [Race Other Asian Code]=27 AND [Ethnicity Not Hispanic Code]=20
then 'Asian Non-Hispanic'
ELSEIF [Race Nat Haw Oth Pac Isl Code]=40 OR [Race Native Hawaiian Code]=41 OR [Race Guam Chamorro Code]=42 then 'Native Hawaiian/Other Pacific Islander Non-Hispanic'
ELSEIF [Race White Code]=999 or [Ethnicity Not Hispanic Code]=998 or [Race Black Or Af Am Code]= 999 OR
[Ethnicity Cuban Code]=999 or [Ethnicity Hispanic Non Specific Code]=999 or [Ethnicity Mexican Code]=999 or
[Ethnicity Other Hispanic Code]=999 or [Ethnicity Puerto Rican Code]=999 or [Race AIAN Code]=999 or
[Race Other Code]=999 or [Race Asian Code]=999 OR [Race Asian Indian Code]=999 OR [Race Chinese Code]=999 OR [Race Filipino Code]=999 OR
[Race Japanese Code]=999 OR [Race Korean Code]=999 OR [Race Vietnamese Code]=999 OR [Race Other Asian Code]=999 or [Race Nat Haw Oth Pac Isl Code]=999 Or
[Race Native Hawaiian Code]=999 or [Race Guam Chamorro Code]=999 then 'Unknown'
Elseif 
END
```

Comment: If you know everyone else has selected multiple races then do `ELSE 'Multiple Race'`

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. I think you need to create another calculated field with respondents having multiple race(add a 1 when respondents select more than 1 on a row) and then refer to that calculated field in the last elseif statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated field for **each** race column to check for a value. For example, for white:

```
\\[White T|F] calculated field
IF [Race White Code] = 20 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

For Black / African American, create this:

```
\\[Black Af AM T|F] calculated field
IF [Race Black Or Af Am Code] = 30 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Once you have calculated fields for **each** race, you can create a calculated field called [multiple races] that sums the calculated fields you just created.  If the sum of the columns you just created are greater than 1, it would indicate multiple races. Here's an example of what this would look like.

```
\\[multiple race] calculated field
IF SUM([AIAN T|F]) + SUM([Black Af AM T|F]) + SUM([White T|F]) >1 THEN "Multiple Races"
ELSE "Not Multiple Races"
END
```

Comment: FYI, INT(<Boolean condition>) is a shorthand equivalent for IF <Boolean condition> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END